# Incorrect syntax near "SESSION"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having my SetCollation method written in C# and there's a sql string

Code snippet

```
private void SetCollation(DbConnection connection, DbTransaction? transaction)
{
    const string sql1 = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = BINARY_AI";
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql1;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    const string sql2 = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC";
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql2;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, when compiling that I get exception in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() (before using directive)  :

> „Incorrect syntax near 'SESSION'.”

I am trying to switch from Oracle to SQL Server

How do I fix that?

Comment: That looks like an Oracle command

Comment: It is, but now I am trying to switch from Oracle to SQL Server

Comment: I guess if I had read the entire question I would have seen that

Comment: SQL Server has no notion of collation on the session level like that. It has a default collation per database, individual collations on columns and you can override it per-comparison using a `COLLATE` clause, but not per session. This functionality should either be removed or replicated in some other way.

Comment: This isn't really a C# question. The issue is with the SQL and the issue would be the same no matter the language used to write the application that executes it.

Comment: "I am trying to switch from Oracle to SQL Server. How do I fix that?" By learning the intricacies of your new DBMS. In this case as mentioned: the collation is at the server, database and column level, as well as with the `COLLATE` keyword on an individual expression. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16